# Put a standalone wall barrier inside a 2D square well potential

Tags: piecewise

Here is the code for the 2D square well potential:

v[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, 58 < Abs[x]}, {1, 58 < Abs[y]}}];
Plot3D[v[x, y], {x, -70, 70}, {y, -70, 70}]

Is Piecewise the right function to use?
How do I put a standalone wall barrier inside this square well potential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot3D[1 - HeavisidePi[x/116, y/116], 
    {x, -70, 70}, {y, -70, 70},
    PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

---

```
Plot3D[1 - HeavisidePi[x/116, y/116] + 
       HeavisidePi[x/2, y/116],
 {x, -70, 70}, {y, -70, 70},
 Mesh -> 50,
 PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Comment: Then please accept ($\checkmark$).